# $_POST is returning empty array

Tags: php, html, post

I've gone through a lot of forums today to figure out exactly why this is happening. I've set up PHPMailer and everything works fine. However, at the top of the code you can see that I attempt to define variables which are initialized with $_POST, however for example if I run var_dump($_POST['name']); it will return NULL for the value. The form data simply is not being sent over. It might be a simple mistake but insight would be appreciated.

PHP Code:

```
       <?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    print_r($_POST['name']);

    // if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    //     $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    // }
    // if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    //     $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    // }
    // if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
    //     $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
    // }

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxx');     // Add a recipient

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = "Contact Request Form From $name";
    $mail->Body = "
        <table width='450px'>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Name: </strong></td>
                    <td>$name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Email: </strong></td>
                    <td>$email</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Message: </strong></td>
                    <td>$message</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    ";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }

?>
```

Here is my HTML form code:

```
<div class="contact-form">
      <h3>Contact Me</h3>
      <p>Please use the form below to get in contact with me</p>
      <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name-1">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name-1" placeholder="Enter Name" class="style">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email-1">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email-1" placeholder="Enter Email" class="style">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message-1">Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="message-1" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn confirm">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
// If submit button is clicked on contact form
document.querySelector('.confirm').onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = 'confirmed.html';
}
```

Comment: you need to add your code here

Comment: Paste your html and php code.

Comment: complete PHP code please from process.php

Comment: @AmitSharma Posted complete PHP code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My apologies. I got a null value when using var_dump($_POST['name']); I will edit the question appropriately.

Comment: any error you are getting or blank screen because it is working fine

Comment: @AmitSharma The email does get sent when I hit the submit button. However, $name = $_POST['name']; , $email = $_POST['email']; , $message = $_POST['message']; contain no values. Therefore, intended message is not sent nor is the name or email from the person who submitted the form.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST)` and check what it actually contains.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Also yes, I have some JavaScript code to redirect to a page that confirms that the form was submitted.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I ran **print_r($_POST)** and it returns **Array ()**.

Comment: Show your JavaScript code. It might be the problem

Comment: Wait... you have javascript that _redirects_ to a page? Please show us _all_ relevant code regarding your form (including any JS that tampers with the submit)

Comment: @mustafaj Just posted the relevant JS code that could be interfering.

Comment: Now it makes sense. You're never actually submit the form.

Comment: You are reloading the page before going to process.php. When the page is reloaded, $_POST becomes empty, that is why it is showing null values. Either use ajax, or redirect from the php code after sending the email

Comment: Why would you redirect the client to `confirmed.html`? What is it suppose to do? I think you need to read up on how forms work.

Comment: @mustafaj Thank you very much for the help and insight! I will follow your advice.

Comment: yes I did not see your javascript code

Comment: @MagnusEriksson To be frank I guess I simply did not understand the process of how a form is submitted. Thank you for your help and insight.

Comment: you can remove the jquery code if it is not relevant to form. if you need to submit the form with jquery then only you need to add jquery.

Comment: It can definitely be confusing while you learn the basics. We have all been there :-)